# CarouFredsel slides showing same images on next button

Tags: jquery, html

I use carouFredSel and it always worked for me. but now I'm using carouFredSel  in one existing ajax portfolio plugin, it worked for me at one point but creating much problem in another side.

Like: When I click on slides next images, then it again shows me same image but another side when I click on previous images it shows me previous listed images in carousel.

**When I click on next image,**

then Loop works each time when I click on next arrow.

**When I click on previous images after press next arrow number of times,**

then each number of time I press previous button for displaying same images where I start from click next images**
you can see here in vouchers > portfolio item spa/beauty

here's my link
http://dealspandora.ae/

Comment: May I see your code work?

Comment: @tharaka-arachchige you can see here in vouchers > portfolio item spa/beauty
here's my link http://dealspandora.ae/

Comment: You have 3520px width to '.services-section .all_services' try setting higher width to that class. Can you see .spa-beauty_sort elements have more than two rows.

Comment: Dear but same code worked with portfolio item 'All'.

Comment: Did you try removing that? what happned

Comment: @TharakaArachchige Dear yes. I removed rows. which you point out, and it worked well.

Comment: Dear one more thing I notice, that this multiple rows is displaying in even menu items. I'm creating one more portfolio item for confirmation. and I did not increase width of all-services because same width running on my one local website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80993/discussion-between-tharaka-arachchige-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: any help for this question?

Comment: Try to set width according to displayed items. Think if you have 20 items and each one has 250px width. so you need to set (250 x 20) / 2 = 2500. divide by two because you have two rows to display vouchers. you can set this width from jquery not from css.

Comment: Dear Thnx! but now I have use new code. because that time I;m using script in existing plugin. but now I use jquery for display none block. but here's also a little issue. if u can join chat discussion or whatsapp?

Comment: Dear thanx. I used another way remove plugin and used hide show method to display portfolio + carousel posts. but thanx for your precious time.. :-)